# plot seems using data index from data frame in r

Tags: r, plot

**Env**

R 3.3.2  OSX 10.9.3

I was trying to get the degree distribution of a graph from a degree vector using `table`  and then plot as loglog figure after convert to a dataframe. Code below show more detail:

degree info stores in vector Ent$connums. I get frequency using `as.data.frame(table())`. And I do get all data I need succefully.

```
print(Ent$connums)
odf <- as.data.frame(table(Ent$connums))
names(odf) <- c('allk', 'freq')
#print(odf)
d.f <- data.frame(k=odf$allk, pk=odf$freq/nums)
rm(Ent)
rm(odf)

print(d.f$k)
print(d.f$pk)

pdf(file="ba-r-dist.pdf")

opar <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

#####################

plot(
    d.f$k,
    d.f$pk,
    type = "n",
    log = "xy",
    main = "Degree distribution",
    sub= paste("m0 = ", bquote(.(m0)), ", m = ", bquote(.(m)), ", N = t = ", bquote(.(t0))),
    xlab = "k",
    ylab = "p(k)",
    xlim = c( 10^0, 10^3),
    ylim = c( 0.00001, 1),
    xaxt="n", yaxt="n",
    xaxs="i", yaxs="i",
)

lines( d.f$k, d.f$pk, col = "green4", lty = "solid")
points( d.f$k, d.f$pk, bg = "red", col="green4", pch = 21 )
legend("topright", inset=.05, c("p(k)"), lty="solid", pch=21, col=c("black"), pt.bg="red")

axis(side = 1, at = 10^(0:3), labels = expression(10^0, 10^1, 10^2, 10^3))
axis(side = 2, at = 10^(-5:0), labels = expression(10^-5, 10^-4, 10^-3, 10^-2, 10^-1, 10^0))

abline(h=outer((1:10),(10^(-5:-1))), col="#00000033", lty=2)
abline(v=outer((1:10),(10^(0:3))), col="#00000033", lty=2)
```

**The problem**

[image]

d.f is a dataframe. d.f$k stores degree information. d.f$pk stores degree frequency information. The plot should plot d.f$k and d.f$pk. See d.f$k data below for this above figure, there are 41 numbers in d.f$k. The figure seems use 1 to 41 instead of data in d.f$k. In the figure, k starts from 10^0 and end next to 40. It seems that the x value of point is using 1 to 41 which is the data index of d.f$k and the index did not stores in d.f.  The min value of data in d.f$k is 4 and the max value is 102, so the first point should be 4 and the last point should next 10^2.

And there are black bars for each point. I have already tried and found that those black bars is nothing related to legend, although it looks like legend.

If I stores d.f to file and read it using `read.table` and convert it to data.frame and then plot the data.frame, the figure shows correctly. But what happened here, did I miss something?

**data stores in Ent$connums**

```
   [1]  95  79 102  88 102  79  58  83  63  47  21  40  44  23  15  13  29  21
  [19]  38  44  25  45  24  18  16  37  24  32  29   8  21  26  44  24  23   7
  [37]  23  27  11  21  21  15  27   8  27  26  34  22  13  16  15  26  12   9
  [55]  19  16  21   7  16  26  18  15  14  10  20  24   7  18  17   7  27  21
  [73]  24   8  13  25   6  15  15  13  17  39  29   9  18  13   8  22  14   8
  [91]   9  29   8  10   7   7  17  10   7   6  14  12   9  13  14   7   5  14
 [109]   9  13  13   7  12  14   7  13   8   7  16   6  13   8  11  16  11   8
 [127]   5   9  14   4  12  10  16  13  10   8  11  10   8  10  10  16  10  12
 [145]  11  16  19   8   6   7   7   5  11  15   7   5  12   6   5   6  12  10
 [163]   5   9  11   7   7  12  11  10  13   8  10   7   8  10   4   6  13  11
 [181]   7  13   8   6  10   4  10  11   5  11   7  21  15  14   9   7  14  15
 [199]   6   8  12  11  11  11   6  13   6   7   7   9   6   9  12   9   7  13
 [217]  10   9   4  12  11   5   7  12   5   7   6   9   8  11   7   8   9  12
 [235]   6  10   8   9  13   8   6   8   7   4   9   4   9   5  14   6  12   9
 [253]   5   5   6   5   4  12   7   5   7   7   9  11   4   8   8   6   7   5
 [271]   6   7   7   8  11   9   8   8   8   9   6  10  11   4   6  14   5  14
 [289]   4  11  10  15   5   9   6  12   6   7   5   8   5   5   9   7   7   7
 [307]  11   8   5   6   7   7   6   7   4   8   6   7   9   5   5   7   9   5
 [325]  14   9   7  11   4   7   8   6   4   5   7   4  10   9   5   9   6  10
 [343]   7   8  10   7   7  11   4  10  13  10   6   5   5   5   9   6   4   5
 [361]   4   7   7   8  10   8   6   4   7   9   5   8   6   6   4   7   6  10
 [379]   6   6   4   6  11   5   6   7   6   6   8   7   5   6   8   6   5   4
 [397]   5   4   5   7   6   4   6   4   6   4   9   5   7   7   4   6   6   5
 [415]   8   5   6   5   5   6   7  10   4   5   8   7   7   6   8   5   5   5
 [433]   5   5   4   7   7  10   9   4   6   4   7   5   7   5   6   4   8   7
 [451]   9   5   5   5  10   4   5   8   9   6   5   4   7   8   6   4   6   5
 [469]   5   4   4   4   5   5   4   6   6  12   4   5   5   6   6   4   6   7
 [487]   6   5   5   4   5   6   8   6   7   5   4   7   7   5   6   4   5   5
 [505]   7   6   7   4   9   5   6   5   6   4   6   4   4   4   6   6   7   4
 [523]   7   5   6   4   5  10   6   4   4   4   4   4   5   8   8   6   8   4
 [541]   4   4   6   4   4   5   7   5   4   4   4   6   6   5   4   5   8   6
 [559]   5   8   5   5   5   5   4   5   4   7   6   9   4   6   5   5   4   6
 [577]   5   6   7   7   5   5   5   4   5   5   6   6   7   4   5   6   6   4
 [595]   7   7   6   5   5   4   5   7   4   4   5   6   4   4   4   5   6   6
 [613]   4   6   5   9   4   7   4   6   7   6   5   5   6   6   5   4   5   4
 [631]   6   5   5   6   4   4   5   5   5   4   5   5   4   5   5   7   5   5
 [649]   7   6   4   5   4   4   4   4   5   5   4   6   5   4   4   5   4   5
 [667]   4   4   5   4   5   5   5   6   4   8   4   5   4   4   6   5   4   5
 [685]   6   8   5   5   4   6   7   4   5   8   7   4   4   4   5   5   4   4
 [703]   6   5   5   5   5   5   5   4   4   4   4   5   4   5   6   4   4   4
 [721]   5   4   4   4   4   4   8   4   4   5   7   4   5   4   6   6   4   4
 [739]   4   5   5   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   5   4   5   4   4   5
 [757]   4   4   5   5   4   5   6   5   4   5   5   4   5   5   4   4   5   5
 [775]   5   4   5   4   4   7   4   4   4   4   5   4   5   4   4   4   5   5
 [793]   5   4   5   5   4   5   4   5   4   5   5   6   4   5   4   4   4   5
 [811]   4   5   5   4   4   4   4   6   4   4   4   5   4   4   4   4   4   5
 [829]   4   4   4   4   4   6   5   4   4   4   5   5   4   7   4   4   5   4
 [847]   5   4   4   4   5   4   5   4   5   4   4   5   4   4   4   4   5   4
 [865]   4   4   4   4   4   4   5   4   4   5   6   4   4   4   4   4   4   5
 [883]   4   4   5   4   4   5   4   4   4   5   4   4   4   4   4   5   4   4
 [901]   4   5   4   4   4   5   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
 [919]   5   4   6   4   4   4   4   5   4   4   4   5   4   4   4   4   4   4
 [937]   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
 [955]   4   4   4   5   4   4   5   4   5   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   5   4
 [973]   4   4   4   5   4   4   4   5   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
 [991]   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
```

**d.f$k**

```
[1] 4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22 
[20] 23  24  25  26  27  29  32  34  37  38  39  40  44  45  47  58  63  79  83 
[39] 88  95  102
41 Levels: 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 ... 102
```

**d.f$pk**

```
[1] 0.3237051793 0.2021912351 0.1115537849 0.0906374502 0.0527888446
[6] 0.0368525896 0.0298804781 0.0239043825 0.0169322709 0.0179282869
[11] 0.0129482072 0.0099601594 0.0089641434 0.0029880478 0.0039840637
[16] 0.0019920319 0.0009960159 0.0079681275 0.0019920319 0.0029880478
[21] 0.0049800797 0.0019920319 0.0039840637 0.0039840637 0.0039840637
[26] 0.0009960159 0.0009960159 0.0009960159 0.0009960159 0.0009960159
[31] 0.0009960159 0.0029880478 0.0009960159 0.0009960159 0.0009960159
[36] 0.0009960159 0.0019920319 0.0009960159 0.0009960159 0.0009960159
[41] 0.0019920319
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem  comes from the fact that `d.f$k` are factors:

> d.f$k
>   41 Levels: 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 ... 102

The horizontal bars in your plot is because R is trying to plot a boxplot instead a scatterplot. Given the amount of indication in your post, it is not clear why d.f$k are factors but doing a

```
df$k = as.numeric(d.f$k)
```

should solve your problem.

Edit:
As @MikeWise correctly noticed, the correct command is

```
df$k = as.numeric(as.character(d.f$k))
```

`as.characters()` is needed because factors are internally coded as integers and `as.numeric(df$k)` would just returns the integer codes of factors. `as.character(df$k)` converts the factor names to character (and the factor codes are removed) so that `as.numeric(as.character(df$k))` converts the characters corresponding to each factors to numbers

Comment: Yes I tried `is.numeric(d.f$k) is.factor(d.f$k) is.numeric(d.f$k[1])` . It shows [1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE.  It might be `table` make it to factor.

Comment: Actually you usually have to do `as.numeric(as.character(d.f$k))`, otherwise it will just convert them to the numeric equivalents of the factors. Try it out with some fake data and you will see what I mean. Been there, have the burns to show for it.

Comment: `as.numeric(as.character(d.f$k))` works. Why using `as.character`? Is it another question?

Comment: @xraynaud, it would be good if you explained why you have to use `as.character` ... as you are getting the points :)

Comment: This is because factors are internally coded as integers. So as.numeric(df$k) just returns the integer codes of factors. as.character(df$k) converts the factor names to character (and the factor codes are removed). as.numeric(as.character(df$k)) converts the characters to numbers.

Comment: You could ask another question, but it has probably been asked way back at the begining of R questions on stackoverflow. Everyone gets burnt by this.

Comment: Thanks you guys, I got it. And I thinks It might be `table` to make it as factors. But It should be another question.

Comment: `One way to create a table is using the table command. The arguments it takes is a vector of factors, and it calculates the frequency that each factor occurs.` [ref:one-way-tables](http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/types.html#one-way-tables)